# Multiple random slopes & intercepts in lme with crossed variables

Tags: r, lme4, mixed-models, nlme, random-effects

I'm creating a linear mixed model using the `lme` package because I need to specify an AR1 correlational structure and heterogenous variance to the data (it's time series data of 3 separate stimuli).

I have 2 variables of interest - CS & sec - that are both fixed variables but **sec** is on the y-axis and **CS** is the grouping variable. Each CS is measured at each sec and thus they are crossed variables and I have reason to believe I need to model separate random slopes and intercepts for both. My original model looked like this:

`model <- lme(DV ~ CS + sec + CS:sec, random = ~CS|subject, method = "ML", data = df)`

But this only models a separate slope for each CS. I know from reading that modeling crossed random variables in `lme` is a chore and have read [this](https://biostatmatt.com/archives/2718) about how to potentially go about it. Unfortunately, it seems as if this tactic only models the crossed *slopes?* Is there a way to do something similar so that modeling both variables slopes AND intercepts is possible? Does this even make sense within the context of this hack? I know this can be done with simple syntax in the `lmer` command using something as simple as `(slope | g1) + (slope2 | g2)` so it seems odd it can't be done in `lme`